# jquery - for every row that contains string disabled button

Tags: javascript, jquery

table:

```
<table id=tblList>
     <thead>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Action</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          <tr>
               <td>Jane</td>
               <td>Doe</td>
               <td>Pending</td>
               <td><button class="cancelThis">Cancel</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>John</td>
               <td>Doe</td>
               <td>Cancelled</td>
               <td><button class="cancelThis">Cancel</button></td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

and script

```
var search = 'Cancelled';
$('#tblAppointment tr td').filter(function () {
     return $(this).text() == search;
}).parent('tr').css('color', 'red');
```

with code above, i've managed to changed the color of the row that contains "Cancelled" to red

and with this:

```
$('#tblAppointment tr td').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == search;
}).find(".cancelThis").prop("disabled", true);
```

is not working.

should be: for every row that contains string "Cancelled" cancel button will be disabled. rows that doesn't contain string "Cancelled" will remain unaffected.

TIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just add the same logic as the one that is working, Add `.parent('tr')` before `.find(".cancelThis").prop("disabled", true);`

```
$('#tblAppointment tr td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == search;
}).parent('tr').find(".cancelThis").prop("disabled", true);
```

You can cut down you code a bit,

```
var search = 'Cancelled';
var t = $('#tblAppointment tr td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == search;
}).parent('tr');

t.css('color', 'red');
t.find(".cancelThis").prop("disabled", true);
```

**Demo**

```js
var search = 'Cancelled';
$('#tblAppointment tr td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == search;
}).parent('tr').css('color', 'red');

$('#tblAppointment tr td').filter(function() {
  return $(this).text() == search;
}).parent('tr').find(".cancelThis").prop("disabled", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id=tblAppointment>
  <thead>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Status</th>
    <th>Action</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Jane</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Pending</td>
      <td><button class="cancelThis">Cancel</button></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>John</td>
      <td>Doe</td>
      <td>Cancelled</td>
      <td><button class="cancelThis">Cancel</button></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: wow so .parent() is what i'm missing. i haven't think of using it before .find() ..thanks alot

Comment: @silver01 No problem, happy to help

Answer (score 1):

Your initial query is getting a list of `<td>` elements. So when you call find on that, you're only searching inside the `<td>` (which doesn't have a `.cancelThis`) element. You'd have to do something like this:

```js
$('#tblAppointment tr td').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == search;
}).parent('tr').find(".cancelThis").prop("disabled", true);
```

However, I can think of one issue you might want to resolve. What if First or Last named is "Cancelled"? Your query would match that too. If you add a class to the status `<td>`, you can search for it specifically:

```html
<table id='tblAppointment'>
     <thead>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Status</th>
          <th>Action</th>
     </thead>
     <tbody>
          <tr>
               <td>Jane</td>
               <td>Doe</td>
               <td class='status'>Pending</td>
               <td><button class="cancelThis">Cancel</button></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>John</td>
               <td>Doe</td>
               <td class='status'>Cancelled</td>
               <td><button class="cancelThis">Cancel</button></td>
          </tr>
     </tbody>
</table>
```

```js
$('#tblAppointment tr td.status').filter(function () {
    return $(this).text() == search;
}).parent('tr').find(".cancelThis").prop("disabled", true);
```

This will only look at the text of the `td.status` elements, and not the other elements (like first and last name).

Comment: this works too. and now that you mention the other issue. thanks for solving it too.